# How to update record in springboot JpaRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My model is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;   

//getter & setter
}
```

My controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/userProfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String saveUserProfile(@Valid UserProfile userProfile, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        return "userprofileform";
    }           
    userProfileService.saveUserProfile(userProfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/user/home";
}
@RequestMapping("/user/userProfile/new")
public String newUserProfile(Model model) {
       UserProfile profile = userProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(userService.getLoggedInUser().getId());
    model.addAttribute("userProfile", profile);
    return "userprofile";
}
```

Repository is

```
@Transactional
public interface UserProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<UserProfile, Long>{

}
```

When I am creating first time userProfile it creates successfully but when I tried to update same it create new entry.

But in this controller when I use findone() and copy all information it works fine.

Same save method replaced below like :

```
public String saveUserProfile(@Valid UserProfile userProfile, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("userProfile", userProfile);
        return "userprofileform";
    }           
    UserProfile tempProfile = userProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(userService.getLoggedInUser().getId());
    try {                               
        if (tempProfile != null) {
            tempProfile.setName(userProfile.getName());              
            tempProfile.setEmail(userProfile.getEmail());                               userProfileService.saveUserProfile(tempProfile);
        } else {
            userProfile.setUserId(userService.getLoggedInUser().getId());
            userProfileService.saveUserProfile(userProfile);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/user/home";
}
```

Is this write way or how can we update record?.

Or saving in session attribute (@SessionAttributes("yourAttributeName")) is only the write way?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the userProfile object has an id assigned. If your object doesn't have an id, hibernate assumes it's a new entity and therefore it creates a new record in the database.

Comment: Yes I set Id in controller I made call findone with logedin userid and get existing profile object and setid in data came from form request. Also I use hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to confirm that when you want to do an update the UserProfile has an id. Put a debug point at: profileRepo.save(userProfile) to confirm this, as a new Entity will be created if no id exists, and should be updated if the id already exists.

Comment: I checked this and when form submitted that time there is no ID but in my controller manually I am setting id and then save  the record.

Comment: Can you paste the code of where you are setting this manually? 
When you try to update it are you setting it to a new value or the existing value in your database? Also, what value are you setting it to and when it saves what is the new id value?

Comment: I added in code also. `UserProfile tempProfile = userProfileService.getUserProfileByUserId(userService.getLoggedInUser().getId());
userProfile.setId(tempProfile.getId());`